# Is there a better way to write this Jira query?

Tags: filter, components, jira, epic

what is wrong with this code:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("type = Epic", "is epic of") AND 
component is not EMPTY AND "Epic Link" is not EMPTY AND issueFunction 
in aggregateExpression("Total Stories", "count()", "issuetype = Story") 
AND issueFunction in aggregateExpression("Done Stories", "count()", 
"issuetype = Story AND statusCategory = Done") AND issueFunction in 
aggregateExpression("In Progress Stories", "count()", "issuetype = 
Story AND statusCategory = 'In Progress'") AND issueFunction in 
aggregateExpression("To Do Stories", "count()", "issuetype = Story AND 
statusCategory = 'To Do'") ORDER BY "Epic Link"
```

I executed the above query but receiving error

Comment: can you further describe what the goal of your query is?

Answer (score 0):

The function **aggregateExpression** doesn't work like this. It doesn't take three parameters.

It takes two parameters : `issueFunction in aggregateExpression(label, expr)`

**For example :** This query gives you the list of issues in the project "CLITRE". And shows you the number of issues reported by the user "myedes".
[image]

You can also use multiple parameters to show many information.
The query should be like this : `issueFunction in aggregateExpression(label1, expr1, label2, expr2, …​)`

See [reference](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions/calculations#:%7E:text=%C2%A0startOfMonth(%27%2D1w%27).-,aggregateExpression,-Often%20you%20have)